# Determining the equation, center and radius of a circumference using three points

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

**Question**

We are told that a circle has the following 3 points lie on its circumference: $A=(-1,-3), B=(0,-1)$ and $ C=(-1,1).$

I have this polynomial system. In order to complete the problem, we must solve the system of 3 linear equations:

$-D-3E+F=-10,$
$-E+F=-1    $
and $-D+E+F=-2$

Which came from replacing each point in the general equation of the circumference.

**My Attempt**

Every time I complete the system I end up with different values for $D, E$ and $F. $
And the end values for the centre is $(-5/2,-1)$ and radius: $5/2$

How do I resolve this contradiction?

Comment: Could you post the full problem?

Comment: The question is slightly unclear, however, from what I can gather, you just need help solving the system of 3 equations that you have provided. Am I correct in making that assumption?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write this out as a matrix and apply Gaussian elimination (row reducing the matrix into a simpler form to deal with). This is because we have a system of linear equations where we have 3 equations and 3 unknown variables to find.

We start with the matrix where each row represents one of the three equations in the original question and then perform elementary row operations to get this into a simpler form.

$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -3 & 1 & -10\\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & -1\\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & -2  \end{pmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & -1 & 10\\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & -1\\\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 8  \end{pmatrix}$$\rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 7\\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$\rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 7\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$

We could continue, but it is clear what the solution is from here.

We see that $F = 1$ from the final row. We see that $E=2$ from the second row. And the first row tells us that $D+2F=7$ which tells us $D=5$ by substitution for $F$ using the value that we have just found.

Therefore, we are done. We have found that $D=5,E=2,F=1$. We can double check this by substitution back into the original equations and we see that this returns the correct answer in all 3 (showing that we have found the correct solution).

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand matrix and Gaussian elimination, but it helps finding the unkowns letters.

Comment: I’m glad I could help. I won’t spend too much time explaining Gaussian Elimination as there are lots of videos about it online, but it is very similar to the standard elimination method for solving linear systems of equations. It just makes it a bit easier to do this quickly (I would recommend reading up on Gaussian elimination as it speeds up the process significantly when you are working with more than 2 unknown variables).

Answer (score 0):

In-circle:

1. Find the line between points $(A, B)$, $(A, C)$ and $(B, C)$.
2. Find the middle point to each segment;
3. Find the two perpendicular line that intercepts the middle point;
4. Find the circle center as the interception point;
5. Find the distance from the interception and the middle points.

Out-circle:

1. Find the line between two segments $(A, B)$, $(A, C)$ and $(B, C)$;
2. Find the center as interception point between lines;
3. Find the radius as the distance between interception point and some vertex $A$, $B$ or $C$.